# Llenar tabla de MYSQL con otra tabla de la misma base de datos donde la tabla A tiene 1 campo mas que la tabla B

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Como la pregunta lo dice ambas tablas están en la misma base de datos y ambas tienen los mismos campos (tales como nombre dirección teléfono etc...) con la diferencia de que la tabla A(tabla original que contiene los datos) tiene 1 campo mas que la tabla B(tabla a donde van los datos) campo que en la tabla B no es necesario y no debe ser copiado

> INSERT INTO archivo(EXPEDIENTE,NOMPAC,FECHAINGRE,EDAD_A,EDAD_M,SEXO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,TEL,CODSER,CANALIZO,CODDOC,CLAVE,CLAVE2,CLAVE3,cie10) SELECT * FROM muerto WHERE EXPEDIENTE ='0481/02';

por ejemplo con esa sentencia transfiero toda la información de la tabla muerto (para este ejemplo sera la tabla A) y todo insertándola a la tabla archivo (tabla B para este ejemplo)

Esta es la imagen de la tabla B los campos que contiene

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la imagen de la tabla A como verán tienen todos los campos iguales con la excepción de el campo CODCAUSA el cual es precisamente el campo que no quiero ni debo pasar a la tabla B

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que me sale el cual pues es bastante claro el problema es la columna CODCAUSA que no existe dentro de la tabla B y no debe existir entonces hay alguna forma de excluir ese dato a la hora de insertar? igual ese mismo registro traspasado de la tabla A a la B sera borrado así que el dato igual se perderá

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: En vez de usar asterisco en "SELECT * " pon los nombres de los campos que quieres, menos el que no quieres.

Comment: Era tan simple muchas gracias la verdad me la complique mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes indicar que columnas quieres añadir a la tabla B a la instrucción `SELECT` sustituyendo el operador `*` por el nombre de las columnas

```
INSERT INTO archivo(EXPEDIENTE,NOMPAC,FECHAINGRE,EDAD_A,EDAD_M,SEXO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,TEL,CODSER,CANALIZO,CODDOC,CLAVE,CLAVE2,CLAVE3,cie10) SELECT EXPEDIENTE,NOMPAC,FECHAINGRE,EDAD_A,EDAD_M,SEXO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,TEL,CODSER,CANALIZO,CODDOC,CLAVE,CLAVE2,CLAVE3 FROM muerto WHERE EXPEDIENTE ='0481/02';
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando el "*" del SELECT, especificando los atributos que quieres seleccionar. Si no me equivoco seria algo asi.

```
INSERT INTO archivo(EXPEDIENTE,NOMPAC,FECHAINGRE,EDAD_A,EDAD_M,SEXO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,TEL,CODSER,CANALIZO,CODDOC,CLAVE,CLAVE2,CLAVE3,cie10) SELECT EXPEDIENTE,NOMPAC,FECHAINGRE,EDAD_A,EDAD_M,SEXO,DIRECCION,CIUDAD,TEL,CODSER,CANALIZO,CODDOC,CLAVE,CLAVE2,CLAVE3,cie10 FROM muerto WHERE EXPEDIENTE ='0481/02';
```